# String manipulation, when converted show 0 in the beginning of the string

Tags: c++, string

I want to know how can I make the `string` I converted from `DWORD` to `onstringstream` and then to `AnsiString`.

But that doesn't really matter, the conversion could be from `int` to `string`, **I just want to know how I can make every string converted to ALWAYS show `6` digits**, like if my number is `57`, in the `string` it will be `000057`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [io manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) `setfill` and `setw`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream s;

    s << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(6) << 154;

    std::cout << s.str() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: setfill is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @GuilhermeGarcia, yes it is. Check the link and this: http://ideone.com/RSGvj . You need to `#include <iomanip>`

Comment: #include <iomanip> was the needed one, thanks =D and btw there is no need for std::, i can do just s << setfill('0') << setw(6)

Comment: @GuilhermeGarcia, if you `using namespace std;` then you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

So, the question about formatted output?
you can use `iostream::width` and `iostream::fill':

```
// field width
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  cout << 100 << endl;
  cout.width(6);
  cout.fill('0');
  cout << 100 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i'm not using cout, but thanks anyway, hmjd asnwer probably will solve my problem

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you're using cout or different ostream, it's still an ostream.